# How to compute the higher G-theory of the weighted projective space $\mathbb{P}(1,1,m)$ using Mayer-Vietoris sequence?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-k-theory, toric-varieties

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero.
Let $m$ be a positive integer and let $X$ be the weighted projective space $\mathbb{P}(1,1,m)$ over the field $k$.I am trying to compute the higher $G$-theory of $X$.The plan is to use the Mayer-vietoris sequence for the affine open cover of $X$ given by the fan of $X$ using the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^2$, whose ray generators are $(1,0),(0,1),(-1,-m)$.
Let $\sigma_1$ be the cone in $\mathbb{R}^2$ generated by $(1,0),(0,1)$,$\sigma_2$ be the cone in $\mathbb{R}^2$ generated by $(0,1),(-1,-m)$ and $\sigma_3$ be the cone in $\mathbb{R}^2$ generated by $(-1,-m),(1,0)$.
Let $\tau$ be the cone in $\mathbb{R}^2$ generated by $(-1,-m)$.
Then the intersection $U_{\sigma_2}\cap U_{\sigma_3}$ is the affine toric variety $U_{\tau}$ associated to the cone $\tau$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Noting that $\tau^{\vee}$ is the closed half-space in $\mathbb{R}^2$ below the line $y=\frac{-x}{m}$,I showed that the coordinate ring of $U_{\tau}$ is $k[x^{-m}y,x^{-1},y^{-1},y^{-1}x,y^{-1}x^2,…,y^{-1}x^m]$.I am trying to use the $G$-theory localization sequence induced by the homotopy fibration $G(R/y^{-1}R)\rightarrow G(R)\rightarrow G(R[y])$ to compute all the $G$-theory groups of $R= k[x^{-m}y,x^{-1},y^{-1},y^{-1}x,y^{-1}x^2,…,y^{-1}x^m]$.
I managed to show that $R/y^{-1}R$ is isomorphic to the polynomial ring $k[x,y]$ and the localization $R[y]$ is isomorphic to $k[x,x^{-1},y,y^{-1}]$.
Then the boundary map from $G_1(R[y])$ to $G_0(R/y^{-1}R)$ is surjective,so that the map $G_0(R)\rightarrow G_0(R[y])$ is an isomorphism. This is how I computed $G_0(R)$.
Now I am stuck on how to compute the higher $G$-theory groups of $R$.